# Creating a TopoJSON file with countries that also includes sovereign countries

Tags: geojson, merge, topojson

I am looking for a TopoJSON file that includes all countries *including* what I ended up after looking as 'sovereign countries' found in the following link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states

Given the fact that the TopoJSON will be used in D3.js, it is stated that the TopoJSON files used in D3 are using vectors from 'Natural Earth' found here:
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/

However, the list of sovereign countries found in the 'Natural Earth' data is not the same - eg while Monaco is listed in wikipedia as a sovereign country it is not listed in the sovereign countries of natural earth. It is listed in the 'populated places' file though.

I am looking for a file that includes all countries including the sovereign countries - wikipedia version. I don't mind creating what is needed from scratch, so here I am asking for efficient ways to achieve what I want.

Googling around I found out that you can merge multiple GeoJSON files and then convert to TopoJSON, however the processes aren't very clear.

Looking for any pointers, tips, tools - getting a ready file would be an added bonus, but I would like to learn how to do it on myself.

In other words, is it easier to find a list, strip it and merge it?

Is there a way to manually add vectors and additional information on a TopoJSON directly?

Do I need to extract information from it, edit and re-build it somehow?

Comment: Perhaps it is because you downloaded the Natural Earth Data at the 1:110,000,000 -scale, and Monaco is too small to be represented as a polygon at the scale. I downloaded the 1:10,000,000-scale countries, and Monaco is present in that dataset (https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/)

Comment: I like using http://geojson.io for viewing and simple manipulation of geoJSON files, and you can both open TopoJSON files and save to TopoJSON format.

Comment: See also these answers about the difference between geoJSON and its extended version topoJSON (https://github.com/topojson/topojson) and why to use one over the other: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740705/difference-between-geojson-and-topojson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer to my own question. The map I was after is named **Admin 0 - scale ranks** in the 1:10 Cultural vectors - https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/.

Now it's a long process to manually merge a few areas, optimize and simplify but other than that it contains all the sovereign countries I wanted.

Thanks for your time everyone!

Comment: thanks for this answer!  I riffed on this to answer this related question over on the stackoverflow data-visualization tag :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655963/topojson-arcs-for-singapore-and-hong-kong/52584131#52584131

Answer (score 1):

At [GADM page](https://gadm.org/download_world.html) you can fin a shapefile with 256 nations and 339127 polygons.
I downloaded it (536 MB zipped, 2.93 GB unzipped) and check nations names with wikipedia sovereign countries.

In this shapefile you can find Monaco as a Country.
 [image: Monaco]

Wiki list have 234 countries and 198 of them are aesily matched in GADM shape at `NAME_0` column. The rest 36 can be found at `NAME_1`, `NAME_2`, ... columns.

If you are GIS user you can (in order to get the desired layer):

1. Edit the layer table and assign in `NAME_0` column the values of countries (as Transnistria, that can be found at  `NAME_1` column)
2. Once ready your `NAME_0` column values make a dissolve (GIS operation) and get your 234 polygons shape
3. Export the layer at requiered format

Example of not founded country in `NAME_0` but in `NAME_1` column.

[image: Transnistria]

Probably you have to do some manual assignment on layer table.
Missing wiki-list countries using column `NAME_0` (some of them because spelling):

[1,] "Abkhazia"
 [2,] "Artsakh"
 [3,] "Bahamas, The"
 [4,] "Burma"
 [5,] "Congo, Democratic Republic of theo"
 [6,] "Congo, Republic of the"
 [7,] "Côte d'Ivoire"
 [8,] "Democratic People's Republic of Korea"
 [9,] "East Timor"
[10,] "Eswatini"
[11,] "Gambia, The"
[12,] "Holy See"
[13,] "Ivory Coast"
[14,] "Korea, North"
[15,] "Korea, South"
[16,] "Nagorno"
[17,] "Palestine"
[18,] "Pridnestrovie"
[19,] "Republic of Korea"
[20,] "Republic of the Congo"
[21,] "Sahrawi Arab Democratic Republic"
[22,] "São Tomé and Príncipe"
[23,] "Somaliland"
[24,] "South Ossetia"
[25,] "Sudan, South"
[26,] "Taiwan (Republic of China)"
[27,] "The Bahamas"
[28,] "The Gambia"
[29,] "Timor"
[30,] "Transnistria"
[31,] "Abkhazia"
[32,] "Artsakh"
[33,] "Sahrawi Arab Democratic Republic"
[34,] "Somaliland"
[35,] "South Ossetia"
[36,] "Transnistria"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I managed to do it as described in the other answer. The scale ranks file was pretty close to what I wanted and I used openjump to add a couple to not by hand. Thanks though, looks like a nice resource!